# Stored function not-null parameters ms sql server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, linq-to-sql

I have a stored function with some input parametes. I'd like to assert that they are not nulls. But i can't do it. Okay, let's google how to. I see an alternative as

```
    if @DateFrom IS NULL
       RAISERROR ('Parameter @ResourceTypeID cannot be NULL', 16, 1)
```

but

1. It doesn't work with stored functions, but it works only in usp
2. If I have many parameters, I should spam this check for many many lines of code

I can't convert function to usp, so what should I do? I can return -1 or something like this, but it returns me back to 70th, when we didn't have exceptions.

I would like to call it from my L2S code and get an exception if something goes wrong.

Comment: Why about calling your function inside a sprocs and include your parameter check within ?

Comment: I'm calling it from L2S, so buisness logic require return a single value, not a table.